# Variable not found in Symfony Twig

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to the Symfony framework. What I am trying to do is to fetch the data from database and display them in Google Map. Here is my controller class:

```
//removed code
```

However, when I tried to run it, it says `'Variable "locations" does not exist.'`. I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.codereviewvideos.com/course/doctrine-databasics/video/how-to-retrieve-data-from-the-database). I not sure why the `locations` is not declared since I already did it in Controller class.

Sorry but I am new to Symfony. Any helps will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is your bundle name AppBundle?

Comment: Yeah it is the same file structure as from the tutorial. AppBundle then Entity then Crisis.php

Comment: It may be caused by this {% block custom_javascripts %}

Comment: I thought we supposed to enclose by {%%} in twig? If I removed it, it gave me this error message: A template that extends another one cannot include contents outside Twig blocks. Did you forget to put the contents inside a {% block %} tag?

Comment: @lazy_coder Any ideas? I have the totally same file structure as from the tutorial

Comment: It's weard what's happening

Comment: @lazy_coder Do you have any ideas? I even put the for loop under the HTML portion and enclosed with <ul><li> tag but the same error is still showing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access variable in script use it like this.

```
<script>
{% for location in locations %}
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: '{{ location.latitude }}', lng: '{{ location.latitude }}' };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 10
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: myLatLng,
           map: map,
           title: 'Hello World!'
       });
   }
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

No need to repeat script tag in loop.

Comment: Hmm it does not work. The error is still highlighted at the 'locations' in the for loop there

Comment: add {% if locations.count > 0 %} before for loop

Comment: It is still the same as mentioned in the question above. The 'locations does not exists' error message. But I did declared in the controller class.

Comment: Please debug with dump locations in controller and in twig also. Make sure is it same twig file you are rendering.

Comment: Nope, even after added the 'if', the error still persists

Comment: Hmm any ideas? I still can't figure it out

Comment: My file structure is src, AppBundle. Then under AppBundle, I got Controller, Entity, Resources. Under Resources, I got public, views. Under views, I got default and under default, I got the index.twig. Sorry as my reputation is too low to upload a picture

Comment: I realized that when I try to type $this->getDoctrine() in the controller class, the getDoctrine() is not showing under suggestion list. Just wondering could that be a problem?